# mouseMoved not called while mousePressed has been called

Tags: java, mouselistener, mousemove

My `mouseMoved` simply doesn't get called when `mousePressed` has been called, but it gets called normally when `mousePressed` didn't. If I move my mouse while I press a mouse button `mouseMoved` doesn't get called.

```
package src.game.main.gui_hud;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import src.game.main.Game;

public class Slider {

private Color lc,hc,fc;
private int x,y;
private int w,h;
private Runnable change;
private int lineY;
private double value = 100;
private volatile boolean canMove;
public Slider(Color bgColor,Color filledColor,Color handlerColor,Runnable onValueChange,int x,int y,int w,int h,int lineY) {
    setLc(bgColor);
    setHc(handlerColor);
    setFc(filledColor);
    change = onValueChange;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = w;
    this.lineY = lineY;
}



public void render(Graphics gt) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gt.create(x, y, w, h);
    g.setColor(getLc());
    g.fillRoundRect(10, y/2-lineY, w-10, lineY, 10, 10);
    g.setColor(getFc());
    g.fillRoundRect(10, y/2-lineY, (int) ((value*w)/100)-10, lineY, 10, 10);
    g.setColor(getHc());
    g.fillRoundRect((int)((value*w)/100)-6, y/2-20, 5, 30, 10, 10);

}

public void tick() {
    value = Game.clamp(value, 0, 100);
    System.out.println(canMove);
}



public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    Point p = e.getPoint();

    if (new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x+ ((int)((value*w)/100)-6), y + (y/2-20), 5, 30, 10, 10).contains(p)) {

        canMove = SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e);

    }
}


public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p = e.getPoint();

    canMove = false;

}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getX());
    Point p = e.getPoint();


    if(canMove)     System.out.println("LOL");



}











public Color getHc() {
    return hc;
}

public Slider setHc(Color hc) {
    this.hc = hc;
    return this;
}

public Color getLc() {
    return lc;
}

public Slider setLc(Color lc) {
    this.lc = lc;
    return this;
}



public int getX() {
    return x;
}



public Slider setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    return this;
}



public int getY() {
    return y;
}



public Slider setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
    return this;
}



public int getW() {
    return w;
}



public Slider setW(int w) {
    this.w = w;
    return this;
}



public int getH() {
    return h;
}



public Slider setH(int h) {
    this.h = h;
    return this;
}



public double getValue() {
    return value;
}

public Slider setValue(double v) {
    this.value = v;
    return this;
}



public Color getFc() {
    return fc;
}



public Slider setFc(Color fc) {
    this.fc = fc;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Which GUI toolkit do you use?

Comment: Post a sample of your code that duplicates the problem you're having.

Comment: Areg we can't help you in this without code, If you don't know this already there are thousands of reasons why something doesn't work So a sample of code is required to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the code in the `mousePressed` handler, you're trying to do some sort of drag-rectangle, although I can't be certain.

The `mouseMoved` messages will keep happening until you get a `mousePressed` event. Once you've received the `mousePressed` event you will then start to receive `mouseDragged` events until the receipt of a `mouseReleased` event. After that point you will start to receive `mouseMoved` events again.

This is intended to allow differentiating between just moving the mouse and dragging with one of the buttons pressed.

Comment: i love u. helped me more than ANYTHING. Srry my reputation is tooo low to upvote :(